# Get xml-stylesheet when using xml type provider?

Tags: f#, f#-data

How to get the `xml-stylesheet` using xml type provider?

```
let xml = XmlProvider<"""<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type='text/xsl' href='/stylesheets/application_internet.xsl'?>
<application>......</application>""").GetSample()

let stylesheetHref = xml.....?
```

Expect string `'/stylesheets/application_internet.xsl'`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no easy way I know of to get processing instructions and associated data using TypeProviders (or Linq to XML).

It can be done like this, though:

For your example XML `GetSample` returns just the root element content, i.e. `......`. Changing that a bit lets us access the root `XElement`. Knowing the processing node is its preceding sibling, we can get a `XProcessingInstruction` and extract the `url` from its `Data`.

```
#I "../packages/FSharp.Data.2.2.5/lib/net40"    
#r "System.Xml.Linq"
#r "FSharp.Data.dll"

open FSharp.Data
open System.Text.RegularExpressions
open System.Xml.Linq

let href s = Regex.Match(s, "href='(?<url>.*?)'").Groups.["url"].Value

type Xml = XmlProvider<"""<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type='text/xsl' href='/stylesheets/application_internet.xsl'?>
<application><other></other></application>""">

let doc = Xml.GetSample()

let stylesheetProcessing = (doc.XElement.PreviousNode :?> XProcessingInstruction)

// /stylesheets/application_internet.xsl
let url = href stylesheetProcessing.Data
```

Obviously this code expects the XML to always have a valid instruction in the same place. Adding error handling is left as an exercise :-)